# iterate through resultset passed in array

Tags: java, arraylist, resultset

I have passed an ArrayList to another method.
In this method I need to extract the resultset from the ArrayList and iterate through it.
The resultset is being passed no problem.

The problem is trying to extract the resultset from the Array, and because of this I cannot do 
resultSet = GUIsidearray.get(0); does not work, and because of this I cannot do
while(resultSet.next()).

See some of the code sample below. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void updateLocal(ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> GUIsidearray) {

    System.out.println("Get passed Array Value " + GUIsidearray.get(0));
    // Shown in console -> Get passed Array Value
    // [sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet@1adc30] //

    ResultSet resultSet
    resultSet = GUIsidearray.get(0);

    boolean emptyRs = true;

    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            emptyRs = false; // If ResultSet is empty

            String Serno = (resultSet.getString("Serialnumber"));
            System.out.println("Serial Number " + Serno);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: try using for each loop

Comment: Define "does not work." An `ArrayList<Object>` is not a `ResultSet` so you can't expect `ResultSet resultSet = GUIsidearray.get(0);` to compile.

Comment: Does not work = resultSet = GUIsidearray.get(0); -> Change type of 'resulSet' to 'ArrayList<Object>'

Comment: I think it's because of this ArrayList < ArrayList < Object >> GUIsidearray GUIsidearray is an ArrayList, and inside GUIsidearray is another ArrayList.
And GUIsidearray.get(0) will return ArrayList<Object> not a resultset. Can you provide how you add resultset into this ArrayList?

Comment: You should post the code that calls the updateLocal(...) function. I believe you are causing the problem there (or at least it helps us understand what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: Sorry, it wont let me comment as there are two many charaters or answer as I need to wait 8 hours.

Comment: But when you look at the code snippet above I show the console output and it shows that the resultset has been passed.

Comment: System.out.println("Get passed Array Value " + GUIsidearray.get(0));
    // Shown in console -> Get passed Array Value
    // [sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet@1adc30] //

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I was just trying to narrow everything down. Basically if I get the Resultset from the Array i will be iterating through it and adding it to another DB. The SQL code for inserting is not in updatLocal as of yet. The function that call is updateLocal(..) is just a button                               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    
  TempDBUpdate exportArray = new TempDBUpdate();
    
  exportArray.updateLocal(GUIsidearray);
    
   }
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note how the printed representation is this:

```
[sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet@1adc30]
```

and not this:

```
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet@1adc30
```

This suggests that the `ResultSet` you're trying to access is the first element of the *inner* list. So this should work:

```
ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) GUIsidearray.get(0).get(0);
```

Note that **there is almost certainly a better way to get the `ResultSet`.** Without a complete example it's hard to say; you are probably making things more complicated than they need to be. Hint: show us where `GUIsidearray` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have

```
while(resultSet.hasNext())
```

instead of

```
while(resultSet.next())
```

as the first one returns a boolean, the one you implemented returns the next element of the resultSet.

Comment: You might be right, but this isn't the immediate problem the OP is facing. The program doesn't get far enough for this to be an issue.